# Ionic 3 value binding Geolocation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'items' of null
```

This is the result of:

```
</ion-card>
<button ion-button round outline 
(click)="logEvent($startTrackingButton)">Start tracking me</button>
<ion-card>
<ion-item>
<h2>Locations:</h2>
<ion-list no-lines>
<h3 ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemSelected(item)">
{{ item }}
</h3>
</ion-list>
</ion-item>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

(In Component.html), now for its .ts file:

```
logEvent1(TrackNowButton) {

    /*Initializing geolocation*/

    // onSuccess Callback
    // This method accepts a Position object, 
    // which contains the
    // current GPS coordinates
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
        this.items = ([{
            key: "1", value: {
                Latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                Longitude: position.coords.longitude
            }
        }, {
            key: "2", value: {
                Altitude: position.coords.altitude,
                Accuracy: position.coords.accuracy
            }
        }, {
            key: "3", value: {
                Altitude_Accuracy: position.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
                Heading: position.coords.heading
            }
        }, {
            key: "4", value: {
                Speed: position.coords.speed,
                Timestamp: position.timestamp
            }
        }]);
    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError 
    // object
    function onError(error) {
        console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

itemSelected(item: string) {
    console.log("Selected Item", item);
}
```

I hope this is readable... I don´t know what I´m doing wrong in terms of data binding because that's where I think the mistake is...
I also believe that there is something wrong with the part in the .ts file, where I wrote: this.items= (...) as I think that the value can´t be bound to the html or something. 
I´m working on a little program that tracks movements every so often and logs them with the given parameters. Later I want to add Mapbox support but I need to resolve some errors first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you get indicates that `this` is null. Replace the function assigned to `onSuccess` by an arrow function. It will use the correct value for `this`.

```
var onSuccess = (position: any) => {
    this.items = ([{
        key: "1", value: {
            Latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            Longitude: position.coords.longitude
        }
    }, {
        key: "2", value: {
            Altitude: position.coords.altitude,
            Accuracy: position.coords.accuracy
        }
    }, {
        key: "3", value: {
            Altitude_Accuracy: position.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
            Heading: position.coords.heading
        }
    }, {
        key: "4", value: {
            Speed: position.coords.speed,
            Timestamp: position.timestamp
        }
    }]);
};
```

You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert the selected item to a string:

```
itemSelected(item: any) {
    console.dir(item);
    let str = JSON.stringify(item);
    ...
}
```

---

On the other hand, if each item needs to be defined as a string, you can call `JSON.stringify` for each one in the array.

```
var onSuccess = (position: any) => {
    this.items = ([JSON.stringify({
        key: "1", value: {
            Latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            Longitude: position.coords.longitude
        }
    }), JSON.stringify({
        key: "2", value: {
            Altitude: position.coords.altitude,
            Accuracy: position.coords.accuracy
        }
    }), JSON.stringify({
        key: "3", value: {
            Altitude_Accuracy: position.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
            Heading: position.coords.heading
        }
    }), JSON.stringify({
        key: "4", value: {
            Speed: position.coords.speed,
            Timestamp: position.timestamp
        }
    })]);
}
```

Comment: I modified my answer to define items as strings.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize your array as shown below.

```
items:any = [];
```

After that you can push the values like so:

```
this.items.push({ key: "1", value: { Latitude: 
    position.coords.latitude, Longitude: position.coords.longitude });
```

Comment: Now though, There is a problem, that I get an Object as return instead of a string. It literally says: [object, Object], [object, Object]...etc..

Answer (score 1):

Your error indicates that your code is hitting onSuccess method.

You can assign **this** to another variable to be used when the callback function is called.
Keep in mind that call backs don't always execute in the context of the class you are in. Therefor **this** can be undefined.

Here is how you need to do it:

```
logEvent1(TrackNowButton) {
  let self = this;
  onSuccess = (position)=>{
     self.items = [
         {key : '1', value : {} }
         {key : '2', value : {} }
         {key : '3', value : {} }
      ]
  }
  let onError = (error)=>{
     console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
  }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
```